# Problem to configure Tomcat6 + apache2.2 on Ubuntu 10 server

Tags: apache, tomcat, ubuntu, mod-jk

I am trying to configure Tomcat6 with apache 2.2 on Ubuntu server 10. I followed a lot of tutorials but I was not able to make it work...

Please could someone help me??

Here is some information....

The mod_jk.so is located on apache module folder...

My workers.properties

```
worker.list=ajp13
worker.ajp13.type=ajp13
worker.ajp13.host=localhost
worker.ajp13.port=8009
worker.ajp13.lbfactor=50
worker.ajp13.cachesize=10
worker.ajp13.cache_timeout=600
worker.ajp13.socket_keepalive=1
worker.ajp13.socket_timeout=300
```

On server.xml I activated the follow line:

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

I created a mod_jk.conf

```
LoadModule jk_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_jk.so
JkWorkersFile /var/lib/tomcat6/conf/workers.properties
JkLogFile /var/lib/tomcat6/logs/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel info
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y]"
JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories
JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"
JkMount /tomcat ajp13
JkMount /tomcat/* ajp13
JkMount /examples ajp13
JkMount /examples/* ajp13
```

On apache.conf I added the follow line:

```
Include /var/lib/tomcat6/conf/mod_jk.conf
```

My apache log:

```
 [Thu May 05 18:20:53 2011] [warn] No JkShmFile defined in httpd.conf. Using default /var/log/apache2/jk-runtime-status
    [Thu May 05 18:20:53 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9 with Suhosin-Patch mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.6.5 mod_ruby/1.2.6 Ruby/1.8.7(2010-01-10) mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8k mod_jk/1.2.28 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

My tomcat log:

```
May 5, 2011 6:22:26 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
May 5, 2011 6:22:26 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/97  config=null
```

My apache log when I tryed to acces the url/tomcat or url/tomcat/index.html

```
[Thu May 05 18:23:18 2011] [error] [client 200.153.100.51] File does not exist: /var/www/tomcat
[Thu May 05 18:23:21 2011] [error] [client 200.153.100.51] File does not exist: /var/www/tomcat
```

Answer (score 3):

RESOLVED

I writed the lines:

```
JkMount /tomcat ajp13
JkMount /tomcat/* ajp13
JkMount /examples ajp13
JkMount /examples/* ajp13
```

inside the apache.conf, but it was not working because I have virtualhosts, so these lines must be set inside the virtualhost